# JavaScript: Capturing Onkeyup event only works one time

Tags: javascript, key-events

I am trying to write a web page that can catch onkeyup events.

It uses `document.write("...");` to print the keycode each time.

However it only works once, the second time I use it, the window does not update.

Here is the code:

```
document.onkeyup = function checkKeys(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    document.write(keyCode);
};
```

Why does this only catch the event once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write(keyCode);` is overwriting the page each time with the new keycode, you need to append to the document, preferably a div on the page:

```
<div id="keyupDiv"></div>

document.getElementById("keyupDiv").innerHTML += keyCode;
```

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use `document.write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). It's wiping the page clean, along with the onkeyup handler. Create an element on the page and update the element's contents.

```
document.onkeyup = function checkKeys(event) {
    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    document.getElementById( 'results' ).innerText = keyCode;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```